# How can I recover my Yahoo! mail when can't login referenced mail account

Tags: account-recovery, yahoo-account

Both Yahoo! mail account has been locked. I cannot login. I also have forgotten security question of both account. What can I do now?

Answer (score -1):

Try to login Your first yahoo mail account's referenced mail if you forgot security information.If you forget all security information and cannot login referenced mail then you should communicate with yahoo Authority.

Comment: Hi Ibnul, this is not really helpful at all to the OP since he states that he cannot log in to either account and does not remember the security information.