# Choose the option to reset your security questions

Tags: security, account-recovery, passwords, icloud, apple-id

I [expect](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT201485) to see:

[image: I need to reset my security questions]

but see:

[image: e-mail]

and then:

[image: phone]

Not knowing the phone number, how do I proceed?

The clear, explicit, and wrong directions specify:

> Reset your security questions
>
> ```
> Go to iforgot.apple.com.
> Enter your Apple ID, then select Continue.
> Choose the option to reset your security questions, then select Continue.
> ```

As can clearly be demonstrated with the above screenshots:

**There's no option to reset the security questions.**

Today I receive two e-mails from Apple:  that an account had been created with my e-mail and that it had been used to login to `iCloud`.  The e-mails appear legit.  Not being an Apple user I've never used `iCloud` that I recall and cannot guess the phone number they require to [proceed](https://support.apple.com/en-ca/HT204145).

Possibly someone accidentally tried to register with `e-mail`.  Regardless, as its **my** `e-mail`, I'd like to reset the password.

see also:

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8148199

Comment: Why the downvote?  Far better question than:  https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/105481/24327  specific, screenshot, research...

Comment: I don't think this deserves a downvote, personally.  There have been a rash of them over the past couple of days.  I wouldn't worry too much about it.